# Invalid token in Paypal Express Checkout Digital Goods

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm integrating the Paypal Express Checkout for Digital Goods solution on my website and I've ran into a problem.

Here's what I did:

1/ I'm calling `SetExpressCheckoutDG` with my sandbox API credentials. I'm sending the following parameters:

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=3.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&
LOCALECODE=FR&
RETURNURL=https://www.example.com/return.php
&CANCELURL=https://www.example.com/cancel.php
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0
&NOSHIPPING=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=My+digital+good
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=3.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
```

As a result, I'm given a token. So far so good.

2/ I am then redirected to the login page. I did the test while logging with a sandbox test account and as a guest with the same results.

3/ I fill in the card details and then I'm asked to confirm the payment. I click on confirm and I get the `invalid token` error. I checked and I don't alter the token I received in any way before sending it back to Paypal.

What would cause this problem?